# float:right causes parent div to shrink

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="width:50%;"  class="outerdiv">
   <div style="">
            <div style="display:inline;">
                <span><?php echo __('Başlık :', 'goldmem');?></span>
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline; float:right;">
                    <input class="postptext" type="text" id="posttitle">
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

I have this layout. Outerdiv has borders so I can see it's size change. This is the result :

Without float : https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0AYh.png

With float :https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKZOo.png

How can I make it so that the size of the div contains all the elements.

Comment: Just add `overflow: hidden;` to `.outerdiv`

Comment: As a side-note: you can use `<span>` instead of `<div style="display:inline;">`, that's the difference between block-level and inline wrapper elements.

Comment: Adrift awesome !, but why : ( ? Also add this as answer so I can approve.

Comment: Hashem, This code is part of a long time of trials as a part of something much bigger. That is why there are some weird remnants in it.

Comment: Oh now I get it, thanks Adrift.

Comment: You can also add a style of `display: inline-block;` to the outer-div

Answer (score 9):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.outerdiv` - as this creates a new [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) for it's descendants (which are taken out of the normal flow, because they're floated, similar to the way absolutely positioned elements are, but not identical) - it basically allows the container to acknowledge the presence of the float as if it were in the normal flow. The key is to remember that regular block-level elements in the normal flow will ignore a float if it isn't cleared or if a new block formatting context isn't provided.

Comment: +1 but just as a side-note again :D, since the `.outerdiv` element has a width of `50%`, If any of the elements inside has a greater (calculated) width, you won't see the extra width of the element.

Comment: @HashemQolami: Yes, that's true - also note that when I said floats differ from absolutely positioned elements I meant it's because floats will still respect elements in the [inline-formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) (even though not in the normal flow) while absolutely positioned elements won't

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a div at the bottom that will clear all floating items. Add this to your html:

```
<div style="display:inline; float:right;">
    <input class="postptext" type="text" id="posttitle">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And add this to your css:

```
.clear {
    border: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

It will display as is shown here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3q8M/):

Comment: In this case, you might want to consider Nicolas Gallagher's [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)